# Are there any mutual-distance bounding protocols in RFID context?

Tags: protocol-design, attack, timestamping

Distance-bounding algorithms are a classical solution for the Relay Attack, wherein a verifier can determine an upper bound on its distance from the prover.
However, recent literature is discussing the concept of mutual distance-bounding, where both sides of a transaction can measure this upper bound, to overcome the risk of a compromised or even malicious verifier.
However, all these algorithms and proposed protocols, despite being theoretically promising, don't address how a mutual DB protocol, would be implemented in an RFID context; that is a passive RFID tag is one side of the transaction. How can this be done? How can we implement a time-keeping mechanisms on a passive RFID tag to have it approximate or restrict the distance to the verifier?

Comment: Hi Orange! I'm not sure if this is something cryptography can address? It seems like you're asking how the necessary hardware could be developed? Is there some way you imagine cryptography could help here?

Comment: I'm sorry if this is the wrong Stack forum. I just guessed that the relay attack and distance boundinh are a relevant topic to stack crypto.